# How can I make the onMouseOver function run only once? | Html

Tags: html

I have a code when hovering over the button, it prints a letter on the website. How can I make this hovering happen only once?
What I really want to do is hover then the function called a will only be performed once
This is the code:

```
function a(){
document.body.innerHTML += 'uu';
}
</script>
<button onMouseOver="a()">hello world</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `onmouseover` attribute, attach the handler from Javascript and specify the `once` option:

```js
let count = 0;

const a = function() {
  document.getElementById('btnTest').innerHTML = `Button hovered ${++count} times`;
  document.body.innerHTML += 'uu';
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('btnTest').addEventListener('mouseover', a, {
    once: true
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btnTest">This is the button</button>
```

[EventTarget.addEventListener() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @Austin I've updated my answer with a working snippet.